# How do I get the text of a selected row in a table view? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

How do I get the text of a selected cell in a UITableView?  I know how to get the row (`indexPath.row`), for example, but I can't find how to get the contents of the selected cell.

---

The bigger picture:

Ultimately, I want to use the cell to select the appropriate segue.  I am using a plist for the text of a UITableView's cells.  When the user selects an item in the table, the segue is selected.

I set it up like this:

```
switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: segueIdentifier = "segueToTopic0"
    case 1: segueIdentifier = "segueToTopic1"
    // etc.
    default: segueIdentifier = "segueTest"
}
```

but ended up frequently adding and deleting items, or rearranging the plist, forcing me to rearrange this switch statement.

So, now I'm thinking I could do this by using the cell text in the switch statement:

```
switch indexPath.row {
    case "Topic0": segueIdentifier = "segueToTopic0"
    case "Topic1": segueIdentifier = "segueToTopic1"
    // etc.
    default: segueIdentifier = "segueTest"
}
```

(Of course, this means I would have to ensure the text in the plist and the text in the switch statement are identical.)

Or maybe there is a better way?

Comment: If you really feel the need to downgrade the question, how about at least providing an answer on your way out.  I am on here to get answers that I haven't been able to find elsewhere, and to learn.  It is is discouraging and not the least bit helpful when a question is downgraded because it may be trivial to someone more experienced.

Comment: At some point you have an array or something like that that you use in `tableView(_ : cellForRow:)`, you do there `let something = thatArray[indexPath.row]`, or something like that, no? From `something` you set the `text`, no? That's how you retrieve the cell content, by relying on your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking a question here, it's a good idea to think through what you're asking as well as thinking through ***why*** you're asking.

Without additional context, your approach doesn't seem to make much sense.

*"I am using a plist for the text of a UITableView's cells"* ... Might you have 100 "topics" in your plist? Which would mean you have manually created and named 100 segue connections? Likely, there is a much better approach.

However, to answer your specific question...

We assume you have loaded your data from your plist into an array of strings, perhaps called `arrayOfTopics` ... after loading, it will be something like this:

```
arrayOfTopics [
    "Topic0",
    "Topic1",
    "Topic2",
    "Topic3",
    "Topic4",
    "Topic5",
]
```

So, your `cellForRowAt` implementation looks something like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = arrayOfTopics[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Instead of thinking "how do I get the text from a row" just use the same data structure, so `didSelectRowAt` could look like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let segueID: String = "segueTo" + arrayOfTopics[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: segueID, sender: nil)
}
```

If you tap on the 3rd row (rows and arrays are Zero based), `indexPath.row` will be 2... arrayOfTopics[2] contains "Topic2"... appending it to "segueTo" will result in the string `segueToTopic2`, which you can then use as the segue identifier.

Comment: Well, the first sentence was the question and I almost stopped there.  The rest was the "why" - just in case someone had a better idea.  I had actually already implemented  your suggestion to use the data structure into which I had already read the plist (but nowhere near as succinctly as what you showed me).  I very much appreciate it!

Comment: This brings up three more questions:  I've answered the first, that I can indeed uses spaces in the names of segues (though I don't like that much).  The second is: if I am using Storyboard, and have already named the 16 (give or take 5 or so) segues, is there a way to change them to conform to those topic names (spaces and all).  Third, is that you said "Likely, there is a much better approach.".  Suppose I did have 100 segues - what would be the better approach?  If all 100 ViewControllers were created in Storyboard?

Comment: @Greg - that's rather an in-depth discussion, and tough to say without any context. Do you really have 16 ***distinctly different*** view controllers? Are your "topics" that varied? For example, if my topics were "cars, boats, trains, airplanes, etc..." the next thing to show would probably be very similar for each, in which case I would have **one** "detail" view controller, and just display the related information for the topic. But, again, without context I really have no idea what would be appropriate for your needs.

Comment: Yes, there really are 16 distinctly different topics, at least 11, anyway. 
 (Actually 32, but the other 16 can use a single ViewController as you suggested).